# Merge duplicate indices in a sparse tensor

Tags: tensorflow

Lets say I have a sparse tensor with duplicate indices and where they are duplicate I want to merge values (sum them up)
What is the best way to do this?

example:

```
indicies = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

object = tf.SparseTensor(indicies, values, shape=[10, 10])

result = tf.MAGIC(object)
```

result should be a spare tensor with the following values (or concrete!):

```
indicies = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
values = [1, 5, 4]
```

The only thing I have though of is to string concat the indicies together to create an index hash apply it to a third dimension and then reduce sum on that third dimension.

```
indicies = [[1, 1, 11], [1, 2, 12], [1, 2, 12], [1, 3, 13]]
sparse_result = tf.sparse_reduce_sum(sparseTensor, reduction_axes=2, keep_dims=true)
```

But that feels very very ugly

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a solution using `tf.segment_sum`. The idea is to linearize the indices in to a 1-D space, get the unique indices with `tf.unique`, run `tf.segment_sum`, and convert the indices back to N-D space.

```
indices = tf.constant([[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]])
values = tf.constant([1, 2, 3, 4])

# Linearize the indices. If the dimensions of original array are
# [N_{k}, N_{k-1}, ... N_0], then simply matrix multiply the indices
# by [..., N_1 * N_0, N_0, 1]^T. For example, if the sparse tensor
# has dimensions [10, 6, 4, 5], then multiply by [120, 20, 5, 1]^T
# In your case, the dimensions are [10, 10], so multiply by [10, 1]^T

linearized = tf.matmul(indices, [[10], [1]])

# Get the unique indices, and their positions in the array
y, idx = tf.unique(tf.squeeze(linearized))

# Use the positions of the unique values as the segment ids to
# get the unique values
values = tf.segment_sum(values, idx)

# Go back to N-D indices
y = tf.expand_dims(y, 1)
indices = tf.concat([y//10, y%10], axis=1)

tf.InteractiveSession()
print(indices.eval())
print(values.eval())
```

Comment: That is much prettier than what I would have thought of doing

Comment: Thank you. I use your technique to implement confusion matrix under TF compute.

Comment: Great answer. As @SimpleJian mentions this solution works in this case because the (linearized) indices are sorted. In the general case tf.math.unsorted_segment_sum can be used.  Additionally, note that segment_sum and unsorted_segment_sum functions are under tf.math in recent tf versions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
indicies = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]

object = tf.SparseTensor(indicies, values, shape=[10, 10])
tf.sparse.to_dense(object, validate_indices=False)
```

Comment: save my night !!

Answer (score 0):

Using `unsorted_segment_sum` could be simpler:

```
def deduplicate(tensor):
    if not isinstance(tensor, tf.IndexedSlices):
        return tensor
    unique_indices, new_index_positions = tf.unique(tensor.indices)
    summed_values = tf.unsorted_segment_sum(tensor.values, new_index_positions, tf.shape(unique_indices)[0])
    return tf.IndexedSlices(indices=unique_indices, values=summed_values, dense_shape=tensor.dense_shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to use [`tf.scatter_nd`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd?hl=en) which will create a dense tensor and accumulate values on duplicate indices. This behavior is clearly stated in the documentation:

> If indices contains duplicates, the duplicate values are accumulated (summed).

Then eventually we can convert it back to a sparse representation.
Here is a code sample for TensorFlow 2.x in eager mode:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

indicies = [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 3]]
values = [1, 2, 3, 4]
merged_dense = tf.scatter_nd(indices, values, shape=(10, 10))
merged_sparse = tf.sparse.from_dense(merged_dense)
print(merged_sparse)
```

**Output**

```py
SparseTensor(
    indices=tf.Tensor(
        [[1 1]
         [1 2]
         [1 3]],
        shape=(3, 2),
        dtype=int64),
    values=tf.Tensor([1 5 4], shape=(3,), dtype=int32), 
    dense_shape=tf.Tensor([10 10], shape=(2,), dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score -1):

So. As per the solution mentioned above.

Another example.

For the shape [12, 5]:

Lines to be changed in the code:

```
linearized = tf.matmul(indices, [[5], [1]])

indices = tf.concat([y//5, y%5], axis=1)
```