# how to create a frequency tensor out of two tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a tensor like this in which the values are the frequency and the rows are the index(`0 to 6`):

```
tf_docs = 
[[0, 2],
 [1, 2],
 [2, 1],
 [5, 0],
 [0, 1],
 [7, 8],
 [9, 6]]
```

I have a constant tensor, in which values of the tensor are the index:

```
tf_topics = tf.constant([[1 2]
                        [1 3]
                        [1 0]
                        [2 3]
                        [2 0]
                        [3 0]
                        [3 4]
                        [3 2]
                        [3 1]
                        [4 2]
                        [4 1]
                        [2 1]], shape=(12, 2), dtype=int32)
```

I need to check these indexes row-wise in `tf_docs` and the result matrix would be the number of columns in the `tf_docs` in which they are not zero (in both indexes).

For example, We have `[1 2]` in the `tf_topics`. It means check the values in row index `1` and `2` in `tf_docs`. In `tf_docs` the first and second column both values are non-zero. thats why for `[1 2]` the frequency would be `2`.

On the other hand, `[1,3]` get `1` as the frequency. Because one of the value in the second column of the index `3` is  zero.

So the result will be a tensor like this(This is obviously symmetrical). The diagonal will be the sum of frequency of each `index`:

```
[[2,   1, 1, 0, null],
 [1,   3, 2, 1, 1   ],
 [1,   2, 3, 1, 1   ],
 [0,   1, 1, 5, 0   ],
 [null,1, 1, 0, 1   ]]
```

What I have done so far:

I decided to use `tf.gather` and `tf.count_nonzero` over the two matrices. because I wanted to split the `index` in the `topics` and see if these `indexes` co-occurred in `tf_docs`

```
tf.math.count_nonzero(tf.gather(tf_docs, tf_topics, axis=0), axis=1)
```

Though, this seems does not give me the result that I want.

Comment: I think I'm not understanding it well, my impression is that in the result matrix, position `[i, j]` is the number of columns in `tf_docs` where both rows `i` and `j` are not zero, right? (and the diagonal is the sum of each row?) But then, I don't understand how `tf_topics` is used...

Comment: @jdehesa Thank you so much for your help:). the answer for the first question you asked is YES, (YES). `tf_topics` actually we create the `co-occurance` paired using the indexes in `tf_topics`. In the question, the paired for the first dimension is shown. for the second row the pair would be `(3,4) (3,2) (3,1) (4,2) (4,1) (2,1)`. So we just check these indexes in the `tf_docs`.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't follow. If the answer to my first question is yes, then `tf_topics` is not necessary, but you seem to imply it is - which would mean my first assumption is not right. I understand you are getting all two-element combinations from each row in `tf_topics`, but I still don't see how those are supposed to be used. Your result matrix is 5x5, which matches the number of rows in `tf_docs`, not the number of columns in `tf_topics`, nor the number of two-element combinations per row of `tf_topics`. From your last comment, what does "we create the `co-occurance` paired" mean?

Comment: For clarity, what I initially thought you needed can be computed like this: `import tensorflow as tf; tf_docs = tf.constant([[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 0], [5, 0], [0, 1]], dtype=tf.int32); docs_bin = tf.dtypes.cast(tf.not_equal(tf_docs, 0), tf_docs.dtype); mat = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf.expand_dims(docs_bin, 1) * docs_bin, axis=-1); diag = tf.math.reduce_sum(tf_docs, axis=1); mat = mat + tf.linalg.diag(diag - tf.linalg.diag_part(mat)); print(mat.numpy())` However, this does not use `tf_topics`, as explained.

Comment: Now I got why my explanation is not clear. Thanks for giving your solution. Actually, result matrix dimension depends on the largest index in the `tf_topics` as it is `4`, thats why we have `5*5` (0-4). Also, the `tf_docs`could be very large. For example, it could be `1000*1000` matric. I am not interested on all the indexes available on that large matrice but only index being used in `tf_topics`. Here, accidentally, for simplicity I made `tf_docs` small. In reality, `tf_docs` can be a very large matrice with 2000 different indexes, I just want to grab indexes available in the `tf_topics`.

Comment: I changed the `tf_docs` elements

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been re-reading the question many times over and I still cannot understand exactly what you want. Maybe someone more familiar with the problem can help you...

Comment: I see, this is more of a writing problem(obviously english is not my language). I might get some idea of your code in the comment to see if I can fix this. This question is exactly what you already said except instead of looking at the whole `tf_docs` to see which indexes co-occured, we filter out our search criteria with the indexes available in the `tf_topics`. Its like we ignore all the indexes available in `tf_docs` and only consider the indexes being used in `tf_topics`.

Comment: for example, this is my `tf_topics`: `[[1, 2, 3, 0],
                     [3, 4, 2, 1]]`. so here I check the indexes at `(1,2), (1,3), (1,0), (2,3), (2,0), (3,0)` and considering the second row: `(3,4) (3,2) (3,1) (4,2) (4,1) (2,1)`. Thus, if `tf_docs` is `100*100` tensor, only those indexes mentioned above will be checked. `tf_docs` now has `7` row. so the rows in the index 5 and 6 wont get checked.

Comment: I've been also re-reading the question and cannot seem to understand your intent. Kindly provide a more concise and more understandable question and intent.

Comment: @TF_Support Thank you I was trying to solve this. I could not yet. But made some modifications so it should be easier to understand right now.

Comment: @jdehesa I kind of change it so it should be easier to understand. Do you mind having another look please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `nonzero_tf_docs` be defined as:

```
zero_tf_docs = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf_docs, tf.zeros_like(tf_docs)), tf.int32)
nonzero_tf_docs = 1 - tf.reduce_max(zero_tf_docs, axis=-1)
```

The OP is asking to compute the sum `nonzero_tf_docs[i] + nonzero_tf_docs[j]` for each pair of indices `i, j` in `tf_topics` and display the result in a matrix. This can be achieved as follows:

```
def compute_result(tf_topics_, nonzero_tf_docs, tf_docs):
    # Find matrix lower part
    values = tf.reduce_sum(tf.gather(nonzero_tf_docs, tf_topics_), axis=-1)
    max_index = tf.reduce_max(tf_topics) + 1
    out_sparse = tf.sparse.SparseTensor(indices=tf_topics_, values=values, dense_shape=[max_index, max_index])
    out_sparse = tf.cast(out_sparse, dtype=tf.int32)
    out_sparse = tf.sparse.reorder(out_sparse)
    out_dense = tf.sparse.to_dense(out_sparse, default_value=-1)
    out_lower = tf.matrix_band_part(out_dense, -1, 0)

    # Compute diagonal
    diag_values = tf.reduce_sum(tf_docs, axis=-1)
    diag = tf.slice(diag_values,
                    begin=[0],
                    size=[max_index])

    # Construct output matrix
    out = out_lower + tf.transpose(out_lower)
    mask = tf.eye(max_index, dtype=tf.int32)
    out = (1 - mask) * out + mask * diag

    return out


# Find docs without zeros
zero_tf_docs = tf.cast(tf.equal(tf_docs, tf.zeros_like(tf_docs)), tf.int32)
nonzero_tf_docs = 1 - tf.reduce_max(zero_tf_docs, axis=-1)

# Transform counts into matrix format
tf_topics = tf.cast(tf_topics, dtype=tf.int64)
tf_topics_reversed = tf.reverse(tf_topics, [-1])
tf_topics_ = tf_topics_reversed
out_1 = compute_result(tf_topics_, nonzero_tf_docs, tf_docs)
out_2 = compute_result(tf_topics, nonzero_tf_docs, tf_docs)
out = tf.maximum(out_1, out_2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    r = sess.run(out)
    print(r)  # prints [[ 2  1  1  0 -1]
              #         [ 1  3  2  1  1]
              #         [ 1  2  3  1  1]
              #         [ 0  1  1  5  0]
              #         [-1  1  1  0  1]]
```

Comment: Thank you soo much, it works like a charm. Only one question, for some reason I might have repetitive rows at `tf_topics`. For example, `[1 2]` might be repeated two times. in this case it raises an error. is there any way to eliminate the repetitive items?

Comment: Perhaps [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38233821/merge-duplicate-indices-in-a-sparse-tensor) would help.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand the question. However, I'm not sure this is exactly right. You said "The OP is asking to compute the sum `nonzero_tf_docs[i] + nonzero_tf_docs[j]` for each pair of indices `i, j` in `tf_topics`". That would mean, for example, for the pair `[0, 4]` (not present in example) the result would be `0`, but according to the explanation it should be `1`. In fact, in your solution, you can only get `0`, `1` or `2` for non-diagonal elements, right? (for any size of `tf_docs`) But I think OP want the total number of matching columns in `tf_docs`.

Comment: I am not sure if I follow here - what I understand is that missing index pairs (e.g. `[0, 4]`) in `tf_topics` should get mapped to null (or -1 in my code), right? And, yes, my understanding from the question is that non-diagonal elements are 0, 1 or 2.

Comment: @rvinas Sorry, what I meant was, if the pair `[0, 4]` had been part of `tf_topics` in the example, I suppose in your solution it would have gotten a `0`, in the result, right? But I think it is supposed to get a `1`, because rows `0` and `4` of `tf_docs` share `1` column (the second) with a non-zero value. Reading the question again, I see it's not completely clear if it's one way or the other, though.

Comment: @jdehesa Ah, I see what you mean and I agree, the question is not clear enough in this aspect. Good that you provided an implementation for the alternative option :)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to your latest edits and to [rvinas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60921242/1782792) I think I finally understood what you need. One of the things that was confusing me was the fact that there are "null" cells in the output matrix. Anyway, here is a way to do that:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

def freq_matrix(tf_docs, tf_topics):
    tf_docs = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf_docs)
    tf_topics = tf.convert_to_tensor(tf_topics)
    # Sort indices to make upper diagonal
    tf_topics = tf.sort(tf_topics, axis=1)
    # Largest index
    m = tf.reduce_max(tf_topics) + 1
    # Remove duplicates
    topics_flat = tf_topics[:, 0] * m + tf_topics[:, 1]
    topics_uniq, _ = tf.unique(topics_flat)
    tf_topics = tf.stack([topics_uniq // m, topics_uniq % m], axis=1)
    # Make diagonal
    diag = tf.reduce_sum(tf_docs[:m], axis=1)
    # Find non-zero positions in docs
    docs_nz = tf.not_equal(tf_docs, 0)
    # Get for each pair
    docs_g = tf.gather(docs_nz, tf_topics)
    # Find number of matches
    matches = tf.math.logical_and(docs_g[:, 0], docs_g[:, 1])
    freq = tf.reduce_sum(tf.dtypes.cast(matches, tf_docs.dtype), axis=1)
    # Add one to all values to subtract one at the end
    diag += 1
    freq += 1
    # Make upper diagonal
    out = tf.scatter_nd(tf_topics, freq, [m, m])
    # Make symmetric
    out += tf.transpose(out)
    # Add diagonal
    out += tf.linalg.diag(diag)
    # Subtract one to mark empty cells
    out -= 1
    return out

# Test
tf_docs = tf.constant([[0, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1], [5, 0], [0, 1], [7, 8], [9, 6]])
tf_topics = tf.constant([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 0], [2, 3], [2, 0], [3, 0],
                         [3, 4], [3, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2], [4, 1], [2, 1]])
print(freq_matrix(tf_docs, tf_topics).numpy())
# [[ 2  1  1  0 -1]
#  [ 1  3  2  1  1]
#  [ 1  2  3  1  1]
#  [ 0  1  1  5  0]
#  [-1  1  1  0  1]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, yea I know my way of communicating the problems is difficult to understand but Im working on it :D. Again thanks a lot

Comment: @sarii No problem. Note that my answer does not do the same as the other answer (although in the example the result matches), see my comments in the other answer. I'm actually not completely sure which one is what you want, since from the text in the question it could be interpreted both ways. Just make sure you use what you actually need.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again. Do you think you can help me with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61400122/how-to-multiply-each-row-of-a-tensor-to-the-rest-of-rows-element-wise-in-tensorf ? I am stuck in the sense that I even can not break it down to smaller pieces so that I can work on that.